# Silent Push Notifications in iOS 14 and 15

Tags: swift, push-notification, silent-notification

in my app I have implemented silent notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging, I receive message and handle them with:

```
    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Silent push notifications
}
```

But start from iOS 14 I notifications don't come and don't handle when app is turned off fully.

Is there way to get notifications in iOS 14 and 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue when trying to push silent notifications from firebase to Apple devices. A workaround is to use APNs (Apple Push Notification Service) directly. This works reliably in my experience.

Read on how to push notifications using APNs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/

Read on how to push silent notifications specifically here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app